Official draw rules in American checkers
I'm working on a checkers software program and I need to implement the official rules including all possible draws. Following this document, at 1.32.2 it states that the game may end up in a draw, if:

"Neither player has advanced an uncrowned man towards the king-row
during their own previous 40 moves."
"No pieces have been removed from the board during their own
previous 40 moves."

As I understand it, a game can be declared draw after exactly 80 moves or 80 plies of neither player advancing. In my program's code I always reason about the game in terms of plies.
My question is: Did I understand this rule correctly? I have some slight doubts, because I know about the fifty move rule in chess and 50 plies seems reasonably, but 80 feels like too much. And I find the wording in the rules to be a bit weird. So a draw in checkers is considered after 40 plies or 80 plies?

Just to clarify the situation in chess. The 50-move rule is that a player may claim a draw after 50 moves, that is 100 plies, including the ply in the turn where they claim a draw.

@rosie I did not know that! Thank you! So the rule means 50 moves for each player, or is one move considered a full turn (2 plies)? If the latter is true, then I find it very confusing.

50 moves for each player, thus 100 plies (50 White alternating with 50 Black). In chess we number the moves like this: White's 1st, Black's 1st, White's 2nd, Black's 2nd and so on. Not White's 1st, Black's 2nd, White's 3rd, Black's 4th.

Indeed the notation of moves, turns and plies is confusing in many situations.
Sometimes also tricks, rounds and even games can be confusing.

Yes, a Draw is considered after 80 plies (40 turns).
The rules says "their own previous 40 moves", which is equal to 40 plies of each player.
From Definition of a Draw 1.32.2:


Neither player has advanced an uncrowned man towards the king-row
during their own previous 40 moves.
No pieces have been removed from the board during their own previous 40 moves.


